# Amazon SES Not sending message

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have this script to send an html email that I have generated in a php file and is under the variable $message.

`

```html
<?php
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['week'])) {
 $to = $_POST['to'];
 $from = "notifications@lambdachimemphis.com";
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $monday = $_POST['M'];
 $tuesday = $_POST['T'];
 $wednesday = $_POST['W'];
 $thursday = $_POST['R'];
 $friday = $_POST['F'];
 $saturday = $_POST['SAT'];
 $sunday = $_POST['SUN'];
 $notes = $_POST['notes'];
 $message = file_get_contents('./week_email.html'); 
 $message = str_replace('%Monday%', $monday, $message);
 $message = str_replace('%Tuesday%', $tuesday, $message);
 $message = str_replace('%Wednesday%', $wednesday, $message);
 $message = str_replace('%Thursday%', $thursday, $message);
 $message = str_replace('%Friday%', $friday, $message);
 $message = str_replace('%Saturday%', $saturday, $message);
 $message = str_replace('%Sunday%', $sunday, $message);
 $message = str_replace('%Notes%', $notes, $message);
 
 echo $message;
 
 
 
$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'key' => 'key',
    'secret' => 'key',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
));
 
$emailSentId = $client->sendEmail(array(
    // Source is required
    'Source' => 'tes@test.com',
    // Destination is required
    'Destination' => array(
        'ToAddresses' => array('test@aol.com')
    ),
    // Message is required
    'Message' => array(
        // Subject is required
        'Subject' => array(
            // Data is required
            'Data' => 'SES Testing',
            'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
        ),
        // Body is required
        'Body' => array(
            'Text' => array(
                // Data is required
                'Data' => 'My plain text email',
                'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
            ),
            'Html' => array(
                // Data is required
                'Data' => $message,
                'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'ReplyToAddresses' => array( 'test@test.com' ),
    'ReturnPath' => 'test@test.com'
));
}
echo $emailSentId;
echo "fail";
```

I just picked up the amazon api so I have no idea how to debug this to even solve the problem.

I am using the generated credentials from amazon for the script too.

Comment: Try to use a local postfix relay, maybe you will have more logs and explanation

Comment: What do you mean by local postfix?